# New changes on app didn't apply on iOS app store build

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, application-loader, app-distribution

I have an app in app store and I did few bug fixes. Then I uploaded it to the app store and released the build. But after I installed the app, that fixes I did, didn't apply on the build. It is same as the old one. I uploaded the build through `Application Loader`. Why is this happening? Please help.

Comment: too broad of a question with infinite possibilites

Comment: I think Application Loader is your problem. I use Xcode for the lot. My steps for doing an App Store release are always the following: (a) select the generic iOS device, (b) on the menu select Product, Archive, (c) wait for that to complete, when the Organizer will appear, (d) select the top Archive from the list, (e) press Upload to App Store, (f) follow the prompts until we have success. Then go into iTunes Connect and submit for review.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you correctly incremented your app's version, archived your app with fixes, uploaded to iTunes Connect, submitted for review, heard back from Apple with an approval, and distributed to the App Store? If you did all that, things *really* should work.

Comment: Yes. If it's not, the application loader gives an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, set up a script to increment the build number every time you run (or archive) your project in Xcode. [Instructions here](http://crunchybagel.com/auto-incrementing-build-numbers-in-xcode/).

Secondly, add a label somewhere in your app's user interface and populate it with the build number.

```
    self.buildNumberLabel.text = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
```

Now you will be able to confirm, by opening the app on a device, whether the version that is installed is a recent build.